# How to use NSUserDefaults with NSDateComponent to store?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nsdatecomponents

I need to do following things and I need your help in that:

1. create a textfield for user to enter a date. It will happen when user opens the app first time after installation.
2. compare it with current date
3. show the difference.
4. Store the difference so that when App is loaded subsequent times, it shows the loaded difference.

My code looks like this (I will change the constants to input from UITextField later)

```
let currentDate = NSDate()

let dataformatterCurrent = NSDateFormatter()

dataformatterCurrent.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm"

let convertedCurrentDate = dataformatterCurrent.stringFromDate(currentDate)

let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateAskumar = "2015-10-08 14:25:37"

let date1 = dateformatter.dateFromString(dateAskumar)!

let diffDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: date1, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 1))
```

Please help in how to save the diffDateComponents variable with NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Why do you want nsurl? You can just use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What URL? How (and why) do you wish to use a URL for date components?

Comment: I corrected the typo, its NSuserdefault and not nsurl. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: u have to implement `NSCoding` to the `NSDateComponents` to store them in `NSUserDefaults `, but that's not good idea and i don't know if its possible also, i sugesst u to change the difference to String or Int, then very easy to store, like in your case, a string `MMMM dd, yyyy` or  sth is enough

Comment: Why store the components in `NSUserDefaults`? Just store `date1`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the date components in a dictionary, and store that in `NSUserDefaults`.

Example:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute]
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: date1, toDate: currentDate, options: [])
let difference = ["months": components.month, "days": components.day, "hours": components.hour, "minutes": components.minute ]
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(difference, forKey: "difference")
```

This way you don't need to deal with the string representations of the dates. Of course, as @rmaddy pointed out, you could just store and retrieve the other date, if you always compare it to the current date anyway.

UPDATE: I know this doesn't store the whole `NSDateComponents`, so if you need that, you must implement `NSCoding`. But if you're only interested in a few of the components, this could be enough for you.